# removing action in wordpress where action has an array with $this

Tags: php, wordpress, action

I'm trying to simply replace a message that is added by a plugin called 'sensei' from woothemes.

For that my plan was to remove the action that places the message, and then add an action where i copied the normal function and edited to what i wanted it to be.

However the message was never removed and instead my new message is placed on the page next to the default message.

i used this code in functions.php:

```
    add_action( 'sensei_loop_course_inside_before', 'remove_old_course_message', 15 );
    add_action( 'sensei_loop_course_inside_before', 'active_no_course_message_output2', 11 );

    function remove_old_course_message(){
        global $Sensei_Shortcode_User_Courses;

        remove_action( 'sensei_loop_course_inside_before', array( 'Sensei_Shortcode_User_Courses', 'sensei_loop_course_inside_before' ), 10);
        remove_action( 'sensei_loop_course_inside_before', array( $Sensei_Shortcode_User_Courses, 'sensei_loop_course_inside_before' ), 10);
    }

    function active_no_course_message_output2(){
        ?>

        <li class="user-active">
            <div class="sensei-message info">
                This is the message to be shown: 
                <?php _e( 'You have no active courses.', 'woothemes-sensei' ); ?>

                <a href="www.google.com">

                    <?php  _e( 'Start a Course!', 'woothemes-sensei' ); ?>

                </a>

            </div>
        </li>
        <?php
    }
```

(all that changed is that i changed the button in the message to link to google instead of another page, this is so the code is a bit more understandable.)

In the plugin file there is a class named 'sensei shortcode-user-courses' and it contains the code:

```
        if( empty( $active_ids ) ){

            add_action( 'sensei_loop_course_inside_before', array( $this, 'active_no_course_message_output' ) );

        }
```

Comment: This works: remove_all_actions( 'sensei_loop_course_inside_before' );
But it removes something else i dont want to remove.

neither this: remove_action( 'sensei_loop_course_inside_before', 'active_no_course_message_output'); or this: remove_action( 'sensei_loop_course_inside_before', array( 'Sensei_Shortcode_User_Courses', 'sensei_loop_course_inside_before' ), 10);
both dont work.

Comment: i just had a similar problem and remove_all_actions works for me too. So, did you try re-adding the action that also was removed as a workaround?